# Launching apps on iOS 15 from Xcode is too slow

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Launching an app on any of the devices that I have after installing iOS or iPadOS 15 on them is too slow when launched from Xcode

#### **The App would freeze on the launch screen for sometimes more than 10 seconds then it will continue without any problem.**

I tried testing on Xcode 13 and 12 and check all the scheme options. I also tried to create a fresh new project for both SwiftUI and Storyboard.

The app would not freeze if I disabled the 'Debug executable' in the scheme -> run -> info options
Enabling 'Debug executable' would not have any bad effect on devices running iOS 14 and earlier and the app start is fast

the issue is since beta 1 of iOS 15 and still there on the current beta 3 as of now. Since the problem continues to exist on three betas with no-one reporting it more likely to be something related to by setup.

Any help with this issue would much appreciated.

Comment: iOS 15 and iPadOS 15 are both in beta and not released yet, so the issue is quite likely out of your control. Its probably an OS issue that will be fixed in a later release

Comment: That is true but we are on beta 3 at this moment for developers. it really doesn't feel right to have this freeze if you're trying any of the iOS 15 specifics.

Comment: I understand that, but if its happening across a number of apps it can only be the bootloader that loads the apps and runs them, really. which you have no control over... all i can suggest is to raise it with Apple support

Comment: FYI, you’re not the only one. My app experiences this same issue, except it sits on the launch screen for nearly a minute on every Xcode Run. I’m using Xcode 12.x (latest) and the iOS 15 release candidate. The app runs fine after the long initial launch time. I submitted a bug report.

Comment: Have you done any research on this problem other than asking here?

Comment: @zombie I tried deleting the`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport` folder

 seems to have improved but still does not provide immediate response after delivery. Were you able to find a solution to this problem? It seems that disabling "Debug Executable" is the only solution for immediate response after build but I don't think it's right to disable Debug Executable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I still have the same issue with the release version of iOS 15 and Xcode 13. Resetting the device support folder works for me:

1. Delete `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport`
2. Restart Xcode. It will rebuild the device support folder.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683654

Comment: i used this but not changed anything  still taking time